# Automation tool with record & playback option

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

As I know we have selenium IDE tool to record and playback our automation script..while recording in ide some Ajax function and date pickers are not working properly..I want to know is there is any other tool like IDE to record & play back my scripts..

Comment: There is actually plugins for the IDE that will do an implicit wait and then just do a check for text on the page that would be indicative that the ajax call has completed. I would recommend just not using record and playback though.

Comment: This is far too broad to be answered. In general, software recommendation is frowned upon unless it can be properly (narrowly) scoped. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are many. UFT within HP ALM is one such application. You should be able to google them, and find something that will meet your needs.

Comment: This answer is better off as a comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

GhostInspector is another tool I use for UI testing. https://ghostinspector.com/

However I find that all tools and framework struggle with ajax and explicit/implicit waits.

Comment: Do explain why you prefer the tool for which you have given a link.

Answer (score 0):

I personally used HP UFT and Ranorex and tried TestStudio from Telerik and TestComplete from SmartBear. If you're doing black box testing the only realistic way I found to check if an Ajax event is completed is doing what the user will do: to check for visual cue, most of the time a new object created or removed from the page.

Some of those tools have trouble tracking automatically the objects, if that's the case using XPath can help, XPath is supported by all the software I tried.

I also know a few people that use image recognition as the last resort to track an object, I don't know if that's possible with Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could give Ranorex a try. Automated test cases can easily be set up with the capture and replay functionality, as you can read here: http://www.ranorex.com/how-test-automation-works.html. Additionally, it is now possible to execute tests remotely with [Ranorex Remote](http://www.ranorex.com/remote-testing.html).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [SeeTestAutomation](https://experitest.com/test-automation-tool-for-mobile-testing-continuous-integration/): It enables you to record scripts, as well as play them back. You can use it free for 30 days and see if it meets your needs.

Comment: :-) Everything I said on the other post applies here too. Only issue here is that the *question* is a poor one, which means answering it is even harder!!